# No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"

Tags: flask, fabric, pycrypto

I am running some fabric tasks inside of flask. Flask is running inside of wsgi in apache. Once in a while I get this error in the apache logs:

No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"

I then have to restart apache for the fabric tasks that are called via flask to work again.

Any ideas here... I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

```
Fabric==1.5.3

paramiko==1.9.0

pycrypto==2.6

Flask==0.9
```

Comment: // , This is more of a "here is my error, please teh fix" than an actual question. I'm not above asking or answering stuff like this now and again, but have you mentioned anything other than just a restart that you have tried? There are maaaany problems that cause this generic error, and at least as many ways to solve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the answer was to add disconnect_all() to all of my fabric functions. Now the problem seems to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for paramiko from this website: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ouvps.com%2F%3Fp%3D869

Basically, you just need to add a line

paramiko.util.log_to_file("filename.log")

Then all connection will be logged to the file

Not sure where to put that line in fabric